# Algorithm for solving linear equations with nested three banded stripes

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the matrix $M$ of dimension $S^2N \times S^2N$ over the complex numbers that is tiled by $N^2$ distinct $S\times S$ tri-diagonal blocks of $S\times S$ tri-diagonal block matrices. This leads to a matrix with banded stripes of bandwith three.

Are there ways to use the structure of $M$ to solve the associated linear equation faster then general sparse algorithms? What if there is additional structure?

To explain the additional structure; the matrix arises as the self-energy of a 2-point Green's function of a current operator. The current operator as a product of two fields indexed by $\mu, \mu'$ (the band index in physics lingo) at the same momentum $q$ (a point on a discretized torus). The self-energy therefore has the form $\Gamma_{q\mu\mu',k \nu\nu'}$. $S$ is the number of bands. $N$ the number of points on the discretized torus.

$\Gamma_{q\mu\mu',k \nu\nu'} = \Gamma_{q\mu'\mu,k \nu'\nu}^* $  and
$\Gamma_{q\mu\mu',k \nu\nu'} = \Gamma_{k \nu'\nu, q\mu'\mu}^*$.

Since $q$ comes from a torus, some momentum blocks are also related to each other.
The $\mu \mu'$ band off-diagonal entries are small except when the fields are close in energy. Since the band index is ordered by energy, this is generally only possible if $ |{\mu-\mu'}|$ is small, or approximately less then two. Furthermore, one can include more sparsity since the $q$ points with non-negligible band off-diagonal elements are usually a subset of the torus. Also, the bands, that get close in energy may also a subset of the total number of bands.

In symbols  $\Gamma_{q\mu\mu',k \nu\nu'} = \delta_{\mu,\mu'} \delta _{\nu\nu'} \Gamma_{q\mu\mu',k \nu\nu'} + \sum_{w,l \in Q} \sum_{\alpha \alpha' \in B(w), \beta \beta' \in B(l)} \delta_{q,w}\delta_{q,l} \delta_{\mu \mu',\alpha \alpha'} \delta_{\nu \nu',\beta \beta'}  \Gamma_{w\alpha \alpha',l \beta \beta'}$.

To understand $Q$ and $B$ consider the following picture :[image: band structure]
This is a picture of the energies associated to the bands indexed by $\mu$ (vertical axis) at  different momenta momenta (horizontal axis).  The lowest blue line has $\mu = 0$ the one above it $\mu = 1$ etc.
Now $Q$ is the set of momenta where there exist bands with overlapping red regions, as seen by a darker shade of red. $B(w)$ is the set of indices whose bands have an overlap at $w$.

Edit:
To clarify here is a picture. $M$ is a dense block-block matrix composed of $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ $0<i,j<N$ (red blocks). $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ is a tri-diagonal block-matrix $A_{\mu\nu}$,$0<\mu,\nu<S$ (green). $a_{\mu\nu}$,$\mu,\nu<S$ is a tri-diagonal matrix. A line going through a square means it is non-zero. (And on the $M$ scope it would look like a line for large $S$). The in-sets below the diagonal are zoom ins on the different substructures.

Edit2:
I should have named $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ to be $M_{ij}$. For example the red block in the upper left corner has index $i=0,j=0$. So $M$ is a $4x4$ 'matrix' with block matrices as entries.

[image: Image of matrix structure]

Comment: It seems likely that your linear system can be collapsed into a matrix equation using the Kronecker product, but it is hard to tell exactly what your structure is. Eradicate our doubt by explicitly exhibiting the smallest case that is large enough to illustrate the general case.

Comment: The suggestion about the Kronecker product is withdrawn as it requires the blocks to be closely related. What is the exact origin of the linear system. Is it a partial differential equation. Have you reordered the matrix using, say, nested disection? What mathematical properties does the overall matrix have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the structure correctly, then it is possible to reorder your matrix into a matrix that is block tridiagonal. In general, such system can be solved efficiently.

The following MATLAB script generates a matrix which the same sparsity patterns as yours and displays various reorderings of it.

```
% Set dimensions for the test
m=16;
N=4;
S=3;

% Generate matrix using the Kronecker product
T=toeplitz([1 1 zeros(1,m-2)]); A=kron(ones(N),kron(ones(S),T));

% Plot the raw matrix
f1=figure(); spy(A); title('The original matrix');

% Try nested dissection reordering
p=dissect(A);
f2=figure; spy(A(p,p)); title('Nested dissection');

% Try approximate minimal degree reordering
q=amd(A); 
f3=figure(); spy(A(q,q)); title('Approximate minimal degree');

% Try symmetric reverse Cuthill-McKee reordering
r=symrcm(A); 
f4=figure(); spy(A(r,r)); title('Symmetric reverse Cuthill-McKee');
```

Here are the pictures and a few comments. First the original matrix. The use of the Kronecker operator replicates the tridiagonal pattern all over the place:

[image]

The nested dissection algorithm does not yield anything useful. I had misunderstood the problem and thought that there was an underlying PDE whose domain could be decomposed.
[image]

The approximate minimal degree reordering is based on greedy heuristic that tries to eliminate fill-in during an LU factorization. The lower right-hand corner contains the nicest picture of a computer chip that I have seen inside a matrix.

[image]

Finally, the result of the symmetric reverse Cuthill-McKee reordering. It tries to minimize the bandwidth of the matrix. This is the one that you will want to use.
[image]

There is no point in invoking the algorithm every time, rather you should study a few explicit cases and deduce the permutation.

In terms of implementing software, the fastest thing is to treat this block tridiagonal matrix as banded and use the general banded solver from LAPACK: LU-factorization [dgbtrf](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d2d/group__double_g_bcomputational_ga7fc91ba3f250ad3844eba25d59f5d7be.html), forward/backward substitution [dgbtrs](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d2d/group__double_g_bcomputational_ga37ca5bf29c33e026922c06b3bf188513.html#ga37ca5bf29c33e026922c06b3bf188513)

If speed is essential, then there are parallel algorithms that can be applied.
It will be necessary to know if the matrix is, say, symmetric positive definite, diagonally dominant or just nonsingular as well as realistic values of the parameters m, N, S. OP is welcome to contact me directly on this matter.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it may not be the same structure as what I had in mind. What is the parameter $m$? I'll update the question again to clear possible confusion.

Comment: @Ezrael The parameter $m$ is the dimension of your smallest tridiagonal block. I use the matrix $T$ to represent the pattern of this block.

Comment: Ahh yes, I was just confused because $m=S$ in my set up, but it's correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ezrael You are very welcome. It would be valuable for me to know more about the origins of the matrix. Is there a paper that derives the matrix? Are there any physically relevant eigenvalue problems that involve this matrix?

Comment: @Ezrael Note that if $m$ is small, then $T$ is almost a dense matrix and this carries to the overall matrix $A$/ In this case, you stand to gain very little from any reordering, and you are probably better off treating $A$ as dense.

Comment: Yeah the problem was really the scaling for larger S. Realistic materials can have $S$ of $O(10)$. I'll DM you with more info later.